# Is there a way to detect if the current member function is operating on an lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++17

Qualifiers are a great way to overload functions based on context of the object.  Such qualifiers are `const` and `volatile`.  However, writing code for them is annoying as they are usually duplication of code as the cv qualifiers are at least propagated by `this`.  As such, we can make the entire function (sans cv qualifiers) exactly the same using propagation tricks and with the help of `auto` or `decltype(auto)`.

E.g.:

```
struct X {
  int m_i = 0;

  auto& i()                &  { return m_i ; } // returns int                &
  auto& i()       volatile &  { return m_i ; } // returns int       volatile &
  auto& i() const          &  { return m_i ; } // returns int const          &
  auto& i() const volatile &  { return m_i ; } // returns int const volatile &
};
```

Although annoying, at least we can see that this is going to work in all contexts with the same code and thus minimizes error.

However, with the new lvalue/rvalue qualifiers that can be used to specify member functions, `this` doesn't propagate whether the function was called on an object that is an lvalue or rvalue.  This results in having to make slight variations of the function, if say I wanted to do this:

```
struct X {
  int m_i = 0;

  auto&& i()                &  { return           m_i ; } // returns int                &
  auto&& i()       volatile &  { return           m_i ; } // returns int       volatile &
  auto&& i() const          &  { return           m_i ; } // returns int const          &
  auto&& i() const volatile &  { return           m_i ; } // returns int const volatile &

  auto&& i()                && { return std::move(m_i); } // returns int                &&
  auto&& i()       volatile && { return std::move(m_i); } // returns int       volatile &&
  auto&& i() const          && { return std::move(m_i); } // returns int const          &&
  auto&& i() const volatile && { return std::move(m_i); } // returns int const volatile &&
};
```

It would be nice to be able to make them all the same.

Something like this:

```
struct X {
  int m_i = 0;

  decltype(auto) i()                &  { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int                &
  decltype(auto) i()       volatile &  { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int       volatile &
  decltype(auto) i() const          &  { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int const          &
  decltype(auto) i() const volatile &  { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int const volatile &

  decltype(auto) i()                && { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int                &&
  decltype(auto) i()       volatile && { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int       volatile &&
  decltype(auto) i() const          && { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int const          &&
  decltype(auto) i() const volatile && { return std::forward<...some_magic...>(m_i); } // returns int const volatile &&
};
```

Is there any means to interrogate if the current member function is operating on an lvalue or rvalue?

Comment: _`some magic`_ Note that programming languages don't rely on _magic_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, are you serious or you poking fun at my fun? :D

Comment: Puulease, don't format code like that.

Comment: @Adrian I am absolutely serious. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it was meant as an offhand joke.  Should I change it to `...some science...`? :D :D

Comment: @NeilButterworth, it was to emphasize that the code is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The only access you have to yourself within the confines of a member function body is: `this`. And `this` is always a `X [cv]* const`, and `*this` is *always an lvalue* - an `X [cv]&`. It can tell you what the *cv*-qualifiers of the member function are, but it cannot tell you what the *ref*-qualifiers of the function are.

You would have to indirect all of your member functions to a non-member function, passing yourself approrpiately as an lvalue or rvalue:

```
decltype(auto) i() &  { return free_i(*this); }
decltype(auto) i() && { return free_i(std::move(*this)); }

template <typename Self>
friend decltype(auto) free_i(Self&& self) { ... }
```

---

[P0847](https://wg21.link/p0847r2) solves this as well, but that won't be in C++20 either. Maybe C++23:

```
template <typename Self>
decltype(auto) i(this Self&& self) { ... }
```

Here, you can straightforwardly pull off what kind of reference `self` is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using the free function template method, though using a template static member function instead.  I will be very happy when P0847 comes into realization as this is quite annoying.